# Are there any positive uniformly integrable martingales which limit to 0?

Tags: probability, martingales, uniform-integrability

In a recent exam I was asked to show several different properties about a discrete time martingale $X_n$ which is positive, uniformly integrable, with $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n = 0$ almost surely. Are there any processes which actually satisfy this? I believe the following justifies a contradiction:

Since $X_n$ is assumed uniformly integrable and converges a.s. to 0, we also get convergence to 0 in $L^1$ - that is, $E(X_n) = E(|X_n -0|) \to 0$. (For reference, see the last line of [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables)).

On the other hand, since $X_n$ is positive we must have, for some $c>0$,  $\ \ P(X_0 > c) = p > 0$. Thus, $\mathbb E (X_0) \geq p\cdot c$ by Markov inequality and positivity. However, by the martingale property, $E(X_n) = E(X_0) > p\cdot c > 0 $. Thus, we have an inconsistency.

Am I missing something, or was the question degenerate?

Comment: You are not missing anything . The question aske in the exam  is bad.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed solved correctly this question. Actually, this question is not bad as it shows how crucial the uniform integrability assumption is. Such martingale have the representation $X_n=\mathbb E\left[X\mid\mathcal F_n\right]$ where $X$ is integrable, and in this context, by the martingale convergence theorem, the equality $\mathbb E\left[X\mid\mathcal F_\infty\right]=0$ would hold almost surely, where $\mathcal F_\infty$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}\mathcal F_n$.
Exploiting the convergence in $\mathbb L^1$, which is guaranteed by the uniform integrability assumption, is also a good option.

Without the uniform integrability assumption, we may get counter-examples with martingales of the form $\prod_{j=1}^nX_j$, where $\left(X_j\right)_{j\geqslant 1}$ is i.i.d., $X_j$ is positive and has expectation one and for almost every $\omega$,  $X_j(\omega)$ equals, says $1/j$, for $j\geqslant J(\omega)$.